# Problems on the sequence of tenses

Tags: grammar, tenses, sequence-of-tenses

I feel really confused with the sequence of tenses sometimes. I am trying to explain where my problem is. Suppose, I have three different sentences which I want to express in two sentences.

*1) I played cricket on Sunday.*

*2) I watched a movie before playing cricket.*

*3)I met my cousin on Sunday morning.*

After joing first two sentences, we get :

"I had watched a movie before playing cricket on Sunday. "

Now for the third sentence which I want to join in the second line, which tense should I use?

Will it be past perfect again as it happend before another action?

"I had watched a movie before playing cricket on Sunday. I had met my cousin on Sunday morning. "

Even after 5 or 6 sentences if I want to say something which happend even beofre Sunday,  which tense should I use?

Could someone please explain how I can solve my problem?

Comment: If you are simply reporting on the things you did last Sunday, you can just use the past tense for all of them (I did A, then B. then C.). The past perfect is only appropriate if you are describing the cricket match and then want to refer to something that happened earlier. (My cousin came to the cricket match. I had met him at the station that morning.)

Comment: In your first example "I had watched a movie before playing cricket on Sunday", you might say that the perfect is redundant because the past/anterior meaning is conveyed by "before". Just say "I watched a movie before playing cricket on Sunday".

Comment: @BillJ I know I can write that way too but this doesn’t answer my problem. I want to know if my first sentence  is in past tense, second sentence is in past perfect, then which tense will my third sentence be if it happened before the second sentence? I know I can write all the actions in one sentence and it will be very clear  but I want to write in three different sentences to solve my confusion.

Comment: @KateBunting Suppose, I had called him before I met him. Which tense should I use in the third sentence? Should it be : "My cousin came to the cricket match. I had met him at the station that morning. I had called him."?  But it sounds wrong to me!  Please explain.

Comment: "_My cousin came to the cricket match. I had met him at the station that morning. I had called him._" possibly sounds wrong because it has problematic cohesion between the second and third sentences. It sounds ok to me if the third sentence is expanded to make the text as a whole more cohesive: "_My cousin came to the cricket match. I had met him at the station that morning. I had called him beforehand to find out when the train was due to arrive._  See: https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-cohesion-composition-1689863

Comment: Or you could say _I had met him at the station that morning, having previously called him..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After joining the first two sentences, we get : "I had watched a movie before playing cricket on Sunday. "

As general guidance, we only get this in **written** narrative. The past perfect is used mainly in written narrative, in a slightly formal manner, in order to set the scene and/or give the context to an event that will be recounted in the simple past. (In your example, this is “playing cricket.”)

In spoken narrative, e.g. talking to a friend, the simple past is enough, and thus you will have "I **watched** a movie before playing cricket on Sunday."

> Now for the third sentence, which I want to join in the second line, which tense should I use?

In written narrative it will be

"I **had met** my cousin on Sunday morning **and we had** watched a movie, **we then played** cricket."

In conversation, it would be

"I **met** my cousin on Sunday morning, **we** **watched** a movie **and then we played** cricket."

Comment: I have some more doubts. Please look: 

"I had met my cousin on Sunday morning and we had watched a movie, we then played cricket." (................). 

If I want to add something between the brackets which event happened before everything I explained in the first place, which tense should I use?

Comment: If the added event happened before everything else, you would have to use the past perfect - but surely that makes the sentence unnecessarily complicated?

Comment: @techiez Could you give an example of what you want to add between the brackets?

Comment: @Greybeard I had met my cousin on Sunday morning and we had watched a movie, we then played cricket.
................
.................
..................
..................
...................

The above (dot) five sentences happend after we played cricket. 

Now I want to want add a sentence which had happened just before I met my cousin. Suppose,I want to say " I was hijacked " Then which tense should I use?

Comment: In **WRITTEN** narrative it will be: *"I had met my cousin on Sunday morning, we had watched a movie, and then **had** played cricket - and then we were hijacked."* As I said actions that set the scene/give the context to the main event (being hijacked) are in the past perfect. ++ In **CONVERSATION**, it would be *"I **met** my cousin on Sunday morning, we **watched** a movie, and then **played** cricket - and then we **were** hijacked."*

Comment: @Greybeard I am sorry but I haven’t been able to make you understand where my confusion is. You are joing all the sentences together. I don't want that. My confusion comes when they are used separately. The last sentence ( I was hijacked) will be alone itself. And I said that I was hijacked before I met my cousin. Now the correct sentence would be which one : "1) I had met my cousin on Sunday morning and we had watched a movie, we then played cricket. I had been hijacked. 2) I had met my cousin on Sunday morning and we had watched a movie, we then played cricket. I was hijacked. "?

Comment: I'm sorry that I did not understand but it is usual to play cricket **before** being hijacked rather than afterwards - in my experience, hijackers rarely have cricket bats.... And you have not told me if you are speaking or writing the sentences..

Comment: @Greybeard Could you answer the question which I asked in the last comment if I want to write?

Comment: Your write in chronological order. If you are trying to tell me that you played cricket, then "I **had recovered** from being ill and I **had met** my cousin on Sunday morning - we **had watched** a movie, and then **played cricket.**